# How to go about building an expanding fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So, I'm working on a media player application.

I would like to make something similar to Google Play Music's or SoundCloud's slide up mini-player to full-player UX.

I'm not really sure how to tackle that, though. Is it simply two fragments/views? I can understand how to transition onClick with animations, but how would I go about the fluid dragging?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with a fragment, OnTouchListener, and dragging the fragment up. I've done it with a click event and animation with no dragging.

The activity is on the bottom and the container with the fragment placed on top via the xml.

I wouldn't call it expanding though. Its just not fully revealed on screen (i.e. the location is on and off the screen and the fragment isn't actually changing).